# Why is respond_with being removed from rails 4.2 into it's own gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In [rails 4.2](http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2014/8/20/Rails-4-2-beta1/) respond_with has been moved out of core into the responders gem.

Beta release notes.

`respond_with has moved out and into its own proper home with the responders gem.`

Can someone please explain why? What makes the responders gem its proper home? What is wrong with it staying in the Rails gem?

Comment: Why wouldn't something responsible for defining the response belong with all the other responder stuff?

Comment: Cool ... just trying to learn here. I would have thought people using the Rails gem wouldn't want to have to include the responders gem every time in their gemfile since they are most likely going to use it in every application Rails uses.

Comment: Actually I think most people don't use this functionality. It was build with an idea in mind that you can create both an app (with UI) and JSON API at the same time. Practically I've never done that and I worked on quite a few Rails projects.

Comment: Disagree that this is opinion-based.  The decision maker gave his reasons, which I've quoted in my answer.  Yes his decision was based on his opinions, as are all decisions ever, but the answer to the OP's question is factual. Whether one agrees with this decision is of course an opinion, but that is not what the OP asked.

Comment: @MichalSzyndel I actually use `respond_with` a lot as a substitute for inherited_resources/make_resourceful. Anyway, for most apps, it should be possible to create a RESTful app and a JSON API at the same time.

Comment: It is very common for an action to return an HTML (as first reponse) and json in the next one (think paging) this can be very nicely done with respond_to , I think it's a wrong call to move it outside and discourage it as a result.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Rationale from David Heinemeier Hansson (creator of Ruby on Rails):

> I'd like to take this opportunity to split respond_with/class-level
>   respond_to into an external plugin. I'm generally not a fan of the
>   code that comes out of using this pattern. It encourages model#to_json
>   and it hides the difference between HTML and API responses in ways
>   that convolute the code.
>
> So how about we split this into a gem for 4.2, with the current
>   behavior, but also with an option to get the new behavior as suggested
>   here through a configuration point.

Full discussion at this link:

https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/12136#issuecomment-50216483