# "respond_to do |format|" throws UnknownFormat error

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I'm trying to render a js file from a controller with ajax. This exact code always worked before, and it even works in other methods, but I suddenly started getting this error:

```
ActionController::UnknownFormat in MoviesController#vote
ActionController::UnknownFormat
```

Movies Controller:

```
def vote
  ...
  respond_to do |format| #The error points to this line.
    format.js
  end
end
```

vote.js.erb:

```
$('#votes').html("<%= escape_javascript(render 'votes') %>");
```

### The link:

movies.html.erb:

```
<%= render 'votes' %>
```

_votes.html.erb

```
<%= link_to "vote", vote_path, method: :post, remote: true %>
```

routes.rb:

```
post 'movies/vote' => 'movies#vote', as: 'vote'
```

Why am I suddenly getting this error? Why does it work in different contexts but not in this one?

Using Rails 4.0.10

### **UPDATE: Stack Trace**

Application Trace:

```
app/controllers/movies_controller.rb:394:in `vote'
```

Full Trace:

```
actionpack (4.0.10) lib/action_controller/metal/mime_responds.rb:372:in `retrieve_collector_from_mimes'
actionpack (4.0.10) lib/action_controller/metal/mime_responds.rb:189:in `respond_to'
app/controllers/movies_controller.rb:394:in `vote'
actionpack (4.0.10) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
actionpack (4.0.10) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:189:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.0.10) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.0.10) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (4.0.10) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:413:in `_run__1492335060096380544__process_action__callbacks'
activesupport (4.0.10) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.0.10) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.0.10) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.0.10) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:31:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (4.0.10) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (4.0.10) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (4.0.10) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `instrument'
actionpack (4.0.10) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.0.10) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:250:in `process_action'
activerecord (4.0.10) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.0.10) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:136:in `process'
actionpack (4.0.10) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:44:in `process'
actionpack (4.0.10) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:195:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.0.10) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.0.10) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:231:in `block in action'
actionpack (4.0.10) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:82:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.10) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:82:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.0.10) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:50:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.10) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:71:in `block in call'
actionpack (4.0.10) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `each'
actionpack (4.0.10) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.10) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:676:in `call'
warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/head.rb:11:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.10) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.10) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:241:in `call'
rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.10) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:486:in `call'
activerecord (4.0.10) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
activerecord (4.0.10) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:626:in `call'
activerecord (4.0.10) lib/active_record/migration.rb:373:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.10) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.0.10) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:373:in `_run__2656547782179467807__call__callbacks'
activesupport (4.0.10) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.0.10) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.10) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:64:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.10) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:76:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.10) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
web-console (2.2.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:39:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.10) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
railties (4.0.10) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
railties (4.0.10) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.0.10) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (4.0.10) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
activesupport (4.0.10) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
railties (4.0.10) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.10) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
activesupport (4.0.10) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:83:in `call'
rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.10) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:64:in `call'
rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:112:in `call'
railties (4.0.10) lib/rails/engine.rb:511:in `call'
railties (4.0.10) lib/rails/application.rb:97:in `call'
rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
/home/greg/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p648/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
/home/greg/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p648/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
/home/greg/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p648/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'
```

Comment: whats server log error ?

Comment: @7urkm3n I'm not totally sure what you mean, but here's the message in my server: **"Completed 406 Not Acceptable in 2152ms / 

ActionController::UnknownFormat (ActionController::UnknownFormat):
  app/controllers/movies_controller.rb:474:in `vote'"**

Comment: How do you call vote action?

Comment: I thinks respond_to has been remove from rails 4.2 now you need to use responder gem instead.

Comment: @TolerantX It's a standard link, I added that code.

Comment: @kajalojha Really! Do you have a source with details?

Comment: Do you have vote action in routes.rb as "post"?

Comment: @TolerantX Yes, I added that code too.

Comment: Do you have jquery_ujs in your project?

Comment: @TolerantX Yes, and I've never had any problems with it.

Comment: I don´t know which Rails version you have, maybe there is a bug with the version you're using

Comment: @kajalojha But I'm using 4.0.10, so I don't think that could be it.

Comment: @JoeMorano Add your complete stack trace to the question

Comment: @dkp How do I get my stack trace?

Comment: please check this: http://railscasts.com/episodes/24-the-stack-trace

Comment: @JoeMorano you can find it here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25998437/why-is-respond-with-being-removed-from-rails-4-2-into-its-own-gem

Comment: @JoeMorano, Is other methods work in VideoController ? also, do u have somewhere else `respond_to` and does it work ?

Comment: @dkp Sorry for the delay! I added my Application and Full Traces.

Comment: @7urkm3n Yes, other methods work as expected. Yes, I have the same code on a different method that works.

Comment: @JoeMorano can you just add the server log as well in order to just ensure a `js` request is sent to the controller action and add the entire `vote` method definition to your question instead of only `respond_to` section.

Comment: Did you get the answer that worked for you?

Comment: please share your log when the request is just to made to the controller. So that I can give you a concrete answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can specify the `format` option for the route helper to instruct the link to be `js` instead of the default `html`.  Specify it like this:

```
<%= link_to "vote", vote_path(format: :js), method: :post, remote: true %>
```

I've had issues getting that to work with some versions of Rails in the past, but I only have anecdotal evidence about that.  What I found does work in that circumstance is this:

```
<%= link_to "vote", "#{vote_path}.js", method: :post, remote: true %>
```

In the 2nd case, you simply append the `.js` extension to the url path that will trigger the `js` format.  Inelegant and brute force, only to be used AFTER unsuccessfully trying the *right* way, but it does work.

Comment: This brute force append of js... Thanks for sharing it.

Comment: +1 for `format: :js`. But I doubt that the other versions will work. `link_to` returns an `<a href...>...</a>` not just an URL. Adding `.js` to a html `a` tag will return in a visible `.js` string on the page, but doesn't change the link's URL.

Comment: @spickermann Yep, you're right.  It was an error translating from thought to page.  Fixed now

Answer (score 2):

try :

```
def vote
    respond_to do |format|
      if @comment.update(comment_params)
        format.js {render nothing: true}
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @comment }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @comment.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

if statement is run successfully like @comment.update(comment_params), comment is update successfully then it execute formate.js, but if it fails due to some reason then it find else render statement. If it not present, it gives Unknown formate error.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the expected format in the link helper :

```
<%= link_to "vote", vote_path, method: :post, remote: true, format: :js %>
```

Works as well for `button_to`.