# RoR HTML template to .docx

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, docx

I need to create a **.docx** file from a HTML template, so I used [htmltoword](https://github.com/karnov/htmltoword#with-rails) gem.

Usage:

I added the gem (*Gemfile*):

```
gem 'htmltoword', '~> 0.5.1' #last version of the gem
```

I put a route (*route.rb*):

```
get 'preview' => 'foo#preview'
```

And in my *bar.html.erb* I have a link which target's that url:

```
<%= link_to '.docx', preview_path %>
```

Template (*preview.docx.erb*):

```
<h1>foobar</h1>
```

And in the controller (*foos_controller.rb*):

```
class FoosController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :docx

  #other code

  def preview
    respond_to do |format|
      format.docx do
        render docx: 'foobar', filename: 'preview.docx'
      end
    end
  end
end
```

---

However, I'm getting an error:

> ActionController::UnknownFormat

How to fix this error?

My config:

RoR v4.2.4

Ruby v2.2.3p173

---

[Also, there is an open github issue for this/similar topic](https://github.com/karnov/htmltoword/issues/47).

---

**Update**: as @kajalojha mentioned, [`respond_with / Class-Level respond_to`](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/4_2_release_notes.html#respond-with-class-level-respond-to) has been removed to an individual gem, so I [installed the responders gem](https://github.com/plataformatec/responders#installation), however, I get the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I figured it out. I added `format: 'docx'` to the route and it works now.

> Note: as @kajalojha mentioned, [`respond_with / Class-Level respond_to`](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/4_2_release_notes.html#respond-with-class-level-respond-to) has been removed to an individual gem, so I [installed the responders gem](https://github.com/plataformatec/responders#installation).

Let's create a `download` logic.

*Gemfile*

```
gem 'responders'
gem 'htmltoword', '~> 0.5.1'
```

*routes.rb*

```
get 'download' => 'foos#download', format: 'docx' #added format
```

*foos_controller.rb*

```
class FoosController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :docx

  def download
    @bar = "Lorem Ipsum"

    respond_to do |format|
      format.docx do
        # docx - the docx template that you'll use
        # filename - the name of the created docx file

        render docx: 'download', filename: 'bar.docx'
      end
    end
  end
end
```

*download.docx.erb*

```
<p><%= @bar %></p>
```

And I've added some link to trigger the download logic:

```
<%= link_to 'Download bar.docx', foo_download_path %>
```

Which will download the `bar.docx` file with "Lorem Ipsum" in it.

Answer (score 0):

Since respond_to has been removed from rails 4.2 to a individual gem i will recommend you to use formatter gem..

For further details you can look to the link given below.

[Why is respond_with being removed from rails 4.2 into it's own gem?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25998437/why-is-respond-with-being-removed-from-rails-4-2-into-its-own-gem)

Comment: Can you suggest which gem to use?

Comment: I'm trying to find it, but without luck. Can you please post a link?

Comment: [Found it in the docs](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/4_2_release_notes.html#respond-with-class-level-respond-to). Will test it now.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried caracal-rails? You can find it [here](https://github.com/trade-informatics/caracal-rails)

Answer (score 0):

I had to build this same functionality in an app earlier this year and also used the `htmltoword` gem.

```
# At the top of the controller: 
respond_to :html, :js, :docx

def download
  format.docx {
    filename: "#{dynamically_generated_filename}",
    word_template: 'name_of_my_word_template.docx')
  }
end
```

I then have two "view" files that come into play. The first, is my method view file `download.docx.haml`. This file contains the following code:

```
%html
  %head
    %title Title
  %body
    %h1 A Cool Heading
    %h2 A Cooler Heading
    = render partial: 'name_of_my_word_template', locals: { local_var: @local_var }
```

From there, I have another file `name_of_my_word_template.docx.haml` that contains the meat of my Word file.

```
%h4 Header
%h5 Subheader
%div= local_var.method
%div Some other content
%div More content
%div Some footer content
```

When someone hits `my_app.com/controller_name/download.docx`, a Word file is generated and downloaded for them.

In order to ensure this happens, I have a route for the download method in my `routes.rb` file:

```
resources :model_name do
  member do
    get :download
  end
end
```

Apologies for the long reply ... this has worked well for me and I hope helps you through this issue!

Comment: Also the same issue. Which RoR version did you use? Did you include `responders` gem in this project?

Comment: I'm on Rails 4.2.6 and do include the responders gem in my project. Sorry it didn't help!

Comment: I've managed to solved it by adding the `format: 'docx'` part to the route. Check my answer and feel free to add something if I've missed :)

Comment: Glad it's sorted for you!