# active model serializers respond_with causes undefined method "to_model"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, active-model-serializers

I have a simple model:

```
class Receipt
  include ActiveModel::Serialization
  attr_accessor :products
end
```

and my controller is doing:

```
def create
  respond_with receipt, :serializer => ReceiptSerializer
end
```

and the serializer:

```
class ReceiptSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :products
end
```

and I get:

> ```
>  NoMethodError:
>    undefined method `to_model' for #<Receipt:0x007f99bcb3b6d8>
> ```

Yet if I change my controller to:

```
def create
  json = ReceiptSerializer.new(receipt)
  render :json => json
end
```

Then everything works fine...  what is happening???

I was using active_model_serializers 0.9.3, but just tried 0.10.2, and the results are the same.

Answer (score 3):

In all the documentation I've read and personal implementation I use `render json:` instead of `respond_with`.

```
render json: receipt, serializer: ReceiptSerializer
```

I believe that `respond_with` has been removed from rails and isn't considered a best practice anymore but I can't find a link to validate that claim.

Comment: oh, I thought respond_with was the proper way to use ActiveModelSerializers?  did that change?

Comment: I've never used it that way in the 6 years of using Rails. But that doesn't mean it wasn't at one time the proper way to do it. https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/blob/master/docs/general/rendering.md

Comment: respond_with moved to a gem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25998437/why-is-respond-with-being-removed-from-rails-4-2-into-its-own-gem

Answer (score 0):

I'm not totally sure, but it seems in your Receipt PORO, you should rather include: `ActiveModel::SerializerSupport`.

I can't confirm if that works for active_model_serializers 0.10.2 though